# WordPress image URLs have a blank space before /wp-content

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have run into a WP site which is not loading almost all images. The developer tools console shows 100s of these errors.

```
Failed parsing 'srcset' attribute value since it has an unknown descriptor.
Dropped srcset candidate "https://domain.tld"
```

After looking at the source code of the page, I found that the image URLs have a space before `/wp-content/`

This is happening for all `src` and `srcset` URLs.

I have tried troubleshooting by deactivating all plugins, but it did not fix the problem.

How do I go about fixing this issue?

Comment: "*How do I go about fixing this issue?*" Other than telling you to look for the spaces, there is not much else we can tell you based on the information you have given us! We are not mind readers, we do not know your code so we have no idea where the problem might be. Disabling the plugins was a good start but now you need to do more debugging. Have you checked your theme? Try changing it to a default WP theme. If that fixes the problem then you'll need to debug your them code to try find the source.

Comment: Check your website url in options table have you leave the space after the url. There will be two entries in option table. Pls check both

Comment: @AShah I checked that and there is no blank space after the `siteurl` and `home` rows

Comment: @AttiqHaroon did you fix it in the end? I'm having the same issue now

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `siteurl` and `home` setting have a space at the end. The setting can either be found in wp-config.php file or in the database. I had to run the following command to fix it (replace https://example.com with the name your domain)

```
UPDATE `wp_options` SET `option_value` = 'http://example.com' WHERE `wp_options`.`option_name` = 'siteurl';
UPDATE `wp_options` SET `option_value` = 'http://example.com' WHERE `wp_options`.`option_name` = 'home';
```

You might find the following lines in `wp-config.php`:

```
define('WP_HOME','https://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://example.com');
```

Make sure they don't have a space at the end